# SharpZipLib: 1 is not a supported code page

Tags: c#, .net, zip, sharpziplib

I use SharpZipLib to compress file and user got this error:

> 1 is not a supported code page

I found [here](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/19065.aspx) that problem is in regional settings and solution is in

> "replace the line of code that fetches the code page from the Thread's
>   OEMCodePage and instead hardcode the suitable value."

But I didn't find any code example to solve this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Line below hardcodes code page to avoid getting it from system regional settings:

```
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipConstants.DefaultCodePage = 437;
```

Comment: I think the asker would also benefit from an explanation so they don't repeat the mistake.

Comment: Fixed my bug with the Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM. Thanks

Comment: Codepage [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) may be a better choice in some cases. According to the SharpZipLib comments, unicode codepages like [65001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (UTF-8) are not a good idea due to compatability issues.

Comment: This is what's so great about stackoverflow, you have a really weird error happening on just one computer and someone already found the solution.